# How to give an Azure VM access to local network resources

Tags: azure, networking, firewall

I'm new to Azure and my googling has been in effective to resolving my problems.  I think what I want to do is set up a site to point VPN but all of the tutorials deal with making the Azure VM accessible/visible to other machines.

I have MSDN Ultimate and a desktop machine within the company firewall and I can remote desktop into the Azure VM

I have created a VM (Windows 7 enterprise) in azure and want to use it for testing an in house application since I can create the VM with more RAM than I currently have.

The app has been installed and runs, but he application calls out to a web service hosted by a server inside the firewall.

How do I use my desktop machine to bridge the gap and allow the azure VM to call the our internal webservice? I do not need a permanent solution, just something that can configure at the start of a session.

I have no ability to rebuild the app, modify the web service, or make changes to the firewall.  I have complete administrative control over the desktop and call install whatever services and software I need.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a couple of options:

1. Set up a VPN.  However, this may violate your IT departments security policy. [Click Here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/)
2. Use azure service bus, [Click Here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-hybrid-app-using-service-bus-relay/)

Answer (score 0):

One other method that is worth mentioning is RemoteFX for USB redirection of a locally connected USB network adaptor.

This method is not for everyone as it is not instant, requires another network connection and because it is not cost-free (USB network adaptor), but I've found it useful for developing on the cloud and accessing corporate or island networks when working with industrial controllers & embedded systems.

You plug the USB network adaptor into your Desktop, start the RDP session, select the USB adaptor to redirect to the Azure VM, install the drivers for the adaptor on the Azure VM and then set it up like a standard network card (DHCP, or static).  For future RDP sessions the Azure VM will recognize the adaptor and settings the moment it is redirected from your desktop.

### Step 1

You need to purchase a USB network adaptor. One important caveat is that the USB adaptor should **not** be recognized by your desktop computer.  If it knows the adaptor is a netork adaptor (because the drivers are installed on your desktop) then RDP will filter it out from the list of devices that are offered for redirection.  In my application I've used a D-Link DUB-1312 which is not recognized for OSs up to and including Win10 without specifically downloading the drivers.

### Step 2

Setup `RemoteFx` as described in this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2010/06/10/introducing-microsoft-remotefx-usb-redirection-part-1.aspx)

You should then have the computer icon in the toolbar of the RDP session like shown below. Pressing this icon will allow you to select which USB devices to redirect to the remote VM.

[image]

[image]

### Step 3

If your remote VM is Windows 10 then you might need to refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719489/how-to-enable-usb-redirection-in-windows-10/34723097#34723097).