# How to enable USB Redirection in Windows 10

Tags: window, usb

My OS is Windows 7 and I have a remote host Windows 8.1 that I can use RDP to  redirect local usb device to windows 8.1. But the redirect USB doesn't work in windows 10 host.  How can I enable it in windows 10?

Comment: This question has been answered and it's helpful - it would fit perfectly on superuser.com.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I too have had problems using `RemoteFX USB Redirection` on a Windows 7 Client to a remote host on Azure running Windows 10, while the same machine configuration would successfully redirect USB to a Windows 8.1 Azure VM.

To be clear I've not had issues with the USB redirection for common devices (Flash drives, Printers, etc) that are supported with the vanilla setup of Remote Desktop.  This type of USB redirection, for example, allowing me to see a Flash drive that I plug in to my Windows 7 client is working perfectly for me as I can see it in Explorer in the Azure VM.

A comparison of standard RDP redirection and RemoteFX redirection is detailed in this [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Enterprise-Mobility-Security/Introducing-Microsoft-RemoteFX-USB-Redirection-Part-1/ba-p/247035) entry.

My particular USB redirection problem relates to the classes of devices not handled by the basic RDP high-level redirection, and for that I've enabled RemoteFX USB redirection on previous releases of Windows. When this is functioning correctly the computer icon ([image: computer icon]) appears in the Remote Desktop title bar allowing me to select which device should be redirected to the VM.

[image: Titlebar when RemoteFX USB Redirection is working]
<sup>*Titlebar when RemoteFX USB Redirection is working*</sup>

Following the instructions on numerous web resources for enabling RemoteFX USB redirection worked for me for earlier OS versions (i.e. Windows 8.1 on a Azure VM), but would not work for any Windows 10 VM I created.  The titlebar stubbornly remained without the RemoteFX USB redirection feature.

[image: Titlebar when RemoteFX USB Redirection was not working]
<sup>*Titlebar when RemoteFX USB Redirection was not working*</sup>

I finally stumbled across this [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dd35353f-6056-4249-aaeb-57c6ab2588ae/usb-redirectionremotefx-windows-10-enterprise?forum=win10itprogeneral) which solved my problem.

It seems there is one more step needed on a Windows 10 host compared to previous OS versions and that is:

1. Run `gpedit.msc` on the target VM (the target windows 10 Virtual Machine) to start the `Group Policy Editor`. `gpedit.msc` can be typed in from a run dialog (use <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) if you have administrator access, or start an elevated `CMD.EXE` and type `gpedit.msc` from the command line.
2. Locate the item `Computer Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ Windows Components \ Remote Desktop Services \ Remote Desktop Session Host \  Device and Resource Redirection\ Do not allow supported Plug and Play device redirection` from the treeview of the `Group Policy Editor`.
3. Bizarrely set this item to `Disabled`.
4. Run `gpupdate /force` from an elevated command prompt.
5. At least disconnect RDP session and connect again, if this does not work reboot target VM.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to make a few more edits from the thread, posted below in case thread disappears

Comment: It's not bizarre, since you are setting the rule "DO NOT ALLOW" to "DISABLED", which means "ALLOW". However, it doesn't work for me, Win10 on both machines. Upvote though ;)

Comment: I think the Computer Icon is probably actually a printer - unless you're connecting from an  IBM 5150 or similar.

Comment: USB redirection didn't work for me due to RDP Wrapper, more info: https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/issues/2135

Comment: That. Spending hours trying to redirect the device just to figure out I need to explicitly disable an inactive rule that says "Do not allow". Geez.

Answer (score 10):

Do on both Physical Windows Machine and Remote Host

All edits are under the following:

```
Computer Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ Windows Components \ Remote Desktop Services \ >>
```

GPEdits:

- I also changed from "Administrators" to "Administrators and Users" in "Allow RDP redirection of other supported RemoteFX USB devices from this computer"

---

```
Remote Desktop Connection Client \ RemoteFX USB Device Redirection \ Allow RDP redirection of other supported RemoteFX USB devices from this computer (Enabled)

Remote Desktop Session Host \ Remote Session Environment \ RemoteFX for Windows Server 2008 R2 \ Configure RemoteFX (Enabled)

Remote Desktop Session Host \ Connections \ Allow users to connect remotely by using Remote Desktop Services (Enabled)

Remote Desktop Session Host \ Device and Resource Redirection\ Do not allow supported Plug and Play device redirection (Disabled) 

gpupdate /force in elevated CMD Prompt and reboot
```

Comment: I can confirm that these settings are working between a Windows 10 host and client. It does not work properly if the client policies are only applied on the client and the host policies are applied only on the host. Probably it does not require all of the settings on both machines, but I did not invest more time in testing this. My redirected USB device is a 3Dconnexion SpaceExplorer that is used as a 3D mouse for CAD. Please note that the change from "Administrators" to "Admins + Users" refers to "Remote Desktop Connection Client \ RemoteFX USB Device Redirection \ All RDP Redirection".

Comment: I did more testing, and I can confirm the only needed change on the client is "Allow RDP redirection" for **both** Admin and Users (it's easy to miss the dropdown, which was my original mistake). On the host, you only need to _disable_ "Do not allow redirection".

Comment: This works great. Is there an easy way to find the HKLM path so these settings can be edited in Powershell?

Comment: @maafk you should check out Nirsoft RegChange, make a snapshot b4 and then compare to after. Test and make an answer. Im positive there is a way!

Answer (score 4):

You now need to update the machine's policy using
gpupdate /force from the command line. Then reboot the machine for the change to actually take effect and enable the RemoteFX USB redirection option in your Remote Desktop Connection client.
Once it's enabled, access the Local Resources tab, click More under Local devices and resources, and you'll see a new Other supports RemoteFX USB devices setting. You can use this setting to map through many types of USB hardware that you couldn't with vanilla RDP USB redirection.

Answer (score 4):

**USB RemoteFX Passthrough Not working on Some PC's**

I had multiple PC's that met the hardware specs but were missing the Remotefx option in RDP.

The solution was this:

in Programs & Features uninstall the "Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller Driver"

This driver is NOT compatible with RemoteFX passthrough.